# JFileChooser not active window after setLookAndFeel

Tags: java, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

My JFileChooser works fine without the setLookAndFeel added, and it works with it added too, but doesn't automatically become the active window. However, if I make it the active window, then close the window, then press the button that opens JFileChooser again, it becomes the active window. Here is my relevant code:

```
try { 
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

...
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setVisible(true);
chooser.requestFocus(true);
chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));   

int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(chooser);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Under no circumstances should you be doing `chooser.showSaveDialog(chooser)`.  The argument to showSaveDialog needs to be the *parent* of the not-yet-displayed save dialog, usually a Frame.  If you have a main application Frame, pass that as the parent.  Never pass the JFileChooser as its own parent.

Comment: What should I put then? I tried replacing it with null and nothing changed. I'm not really sure what a parent is

Comment: Do you have any other windows in your program?  If so, use one of those.

Comment: I have a stage/scene but it didn't accept either of those as parameters, what should I be using?

Comment: Stage/scene?  Are you using JavaFX?  If so, you should not be using JFileChooser at all, but rather should be using [javafx.stage.FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html).

Comment: Replaced JFileChooser with javafx FileChooser and it works perfectly, thanks very much